# Why are localhost links disallowed?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Time and again I want to add a URL like `http://localhost:someport` to a post, but I can't because it is disallowed.

Why is adding a localhost/intranet link disallowed?

Is there any deeper reason besides stopping not that bright individuals from adding links only they can access ?

Is there a security issue with localhost or intranet addresses, like a visitor can be tricked into clicking `http://localhost/SelfSDestruct` that I should be aware of?

E.g. I had a Problem here:
[PHP installation on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153042/php-installation-on-windows/16427988#16427988) and here: [want to use my ongoing asp.net website on desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992141/want-to-use-my-ongoing-asp-net-website-on-desktop/24992772#24992772)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is blocked because people kept trying to post questions pointing to their server:

> My web server isn't working correctly, the page looks like this: [http://localhost/some-broken-page.html](http://example.com/not-really-a-localhost-link.html)

If you have legitimate reasons to include a `localhost` link, put such links in backticks:

```
`http://localhost:5000/`
```

renders as `http://localhost:5000/`.

Comment: Yea, but it isn't clickable - well not without another page opening :)

Comment: @Quandary: what good would it be to make it clickable? It is of no use for anyone but the small number of people that have the correct service listening on localhost..

Comment: Lazy people wouldn't have to type it in manually (copy-paste-ing is slower than typing it in), and it would remove the potential to mistype the port number ;)

Comment: @Quandary: Copy-pasting is **not** slower than typing it in. Double-click on the scheme, drag to the right. Done.

Comment: A URL that is valid on your localhost is *extremely* unlikely to be valid on someone else's localhost. I can't think of a single valid use case where a localhost link should be made clickable on a public site like SO

Comment: +1 for just stating "people" and not adding any negative adjectives!

Comment: I would add that any link that is just an example and doesn't match any content (at least not from the point of view of most readers) should be placed between backticks, i.e. not just `http://localhost/...` but `http://www.example.com/...` and so on.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Example situation: In the "PHP installation on windows" post. You check if PHP is running by going to http://localhost/helloworld.php for example

Comment: @Quandary: but that link is still valid *only* on your own machine. Not on anyone else's.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: True, but if you follow e.g. the instruction in the PHP installation on windows post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153042/php-installation-on-windows/16427988#16427988) to the letter, it should be valid for pretty much everyone. I doubt anyone else redefined localhost, although you can ;)