# http://localhost is not a link

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

The link http://localhost shows up as an auto-created link while creating the question, but after posting it comes out as normal text.

I noticed this when I posted [this question about 127.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65925026/).  If you look at the question directly, you can notice that that link to http://localhost is normal text.  When you click [the edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65925026/edit), you can see that THE SAME LINK is now an actual link.  Same occurs for this question.  You can click the edit link to see that.

I think that this is happening because SO uses some regex to detect links, that requires at least one dot in the domain name.  http://localhost, on the other hand, does not follow that.  I am not sure if this is how it is done, so any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Yeah, the frontend preview renderer does not use *exactly* the same logic as the backend renderer, occasionally resulting in inconsistencies like these.

Comment: @billynoah OPs question is a bug report about the question preview rendering http://localhost as a link, whereas the "normal" rendered post doesn't.

Comment: @Tom: I think billynoah was thrown off by the "any guidance would be helpful" bit at the end. It seems to be both a bug report and a programming question specific to SO at the same time, though the latter is more intended as seeking context and exposition for the former.

Comment: I presume you can just use `[http://localhost](http://localhost)` rather than relying on the auto detection?

Comment: @MartinSmith: As Tom said, this is a bug report.  It shows two different things in two different places when it should show the same thing.  I could do `<http://localhost>`, but it should work without that.

Comment: I think this is intentional beahviour; related: [Why are localhost links disallowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266999/why-are-localhost-links-disallowed) (which shows that in the past it wasn't even allowed) and [
Meta Stack Exchange
Your post contains a link to the invalid host '192.168.1.1'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134212/your-post-contains-a-link-to-the-invalid-host-192-168-1-1) and [Why are localhost and 127.0.0.1 links blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/why-are-localhost-and-127-0-0-1-links-blocked)

Comment: I couldn't quickly find anything that indicated that this prohibition was changed to simply not rendering as a link, but it looks like it was.